# istringstream "get" method implementation

Tags: c++, stream

The "method" implementation says [istringstream get](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get.html)

```
int get();
Extracts a character from the stream and returns its value (casted to an integer).
```

I wanted to see its implementation.

Edit:Removed the part which I am trying to port

Answer (score 2):

You will find `std::istringstream` in the header `<sstream>`. But not the `get()` method. The `get()` member is inherited from the `basic_istream<_Elem, _Traits>` template which you can find in the header . Here's the implementation, from my VS2005 installation:

```
int_type __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL get()
    {   // extract a metacharacter
    int_type _Meta = 0;
    ios_base::iostate _State = ios_base::goodbit;
    _Chcount = 0;
    const sentry _Ok(*this, true);

    if (!_Ok)
        _Meta = _Traits::eof(); // state not okay, return EOF
    else
        {   // state okay, extract a character
        _TRY_IO_BEGIN
        _Meta = _Myios::rdbuf()->sbumpc();

        if (_Traits::eq_int_type(_Traits::eof(), _Meta))
            _State |= ios_base::eofbit | ios_base::failbit; // end of file
        else
            ++_Chcount; // got a character, count it
        _CATCH_IO_END
        }

    _Myios::setstate(_State);
    return (_Meta);
    }
```